# A sum over symmetric group

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, prime-numbers, symmetric-groups

I want to calculate the following sum over symmetric group:

$$\sum_{w\in S_n}(-1)^{l(w)}n^{l(w)},$$

where $l(w)$ is the number of cycles in the cycles of $w$. For example the element $w=(1)(2)(345)\in S_5$ has $l(w)=3$.

I think it has a very simple expression at least when $n$ is a prime. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

In your notation
$$\sum_{w\in S_n}x^{l(w)}=\prod_{j=0}^{n-1}(x+j)
=x(x+1)\cdots(x+n-1).$$
That's because the number of permutations in $S_n$ with $k$
cycles is a Stirling number of the first kind $s(n,k)$. Stirling
numbers satisfy a two-variable recurrence, and this formula follows
by induction from that recurrence. Substituting $x=-n$ gives your
formula.

Comment: Oh! Thanks a lot for your answer!